# Custom signal not propagating

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, gtk3, gobject

For a project I working on I'm using custom signals which are emitted on a child and then should propagate to it parent when the signal is not handle completely.

Based on the information I could find it seems that not having a handler connected (using `connect`) or returning `False` in the callback should allow the signal to propagate to the widgets parent.

Yet in my toy example below this doesn't work:

```
class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        GObject.signal_new("print-this", GObject.TYPE_OBJECT, GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, GObject.TYPE_BOOLEAN, [GObject.TYPE_STRING])

        self.button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Emit signals")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.emit_signals)

        self.frame = Gtk.Frame.new("Some frame")
        self.frame.add(self.button)
        self.add(self.frame)

        self.connect("print-this", self.got_it)
        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def got_it(self, widget, string):
        print string
        return False

    def emit_signals(self, *args):
        print "Emitting signals.."
        self.button.emit("print-this", "I was emitted from the button")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.frame.emit("print-this", "I was emitted from the frame")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.emit("print-this", "I was emitted from the window")
```

When the signals are emitted I would expect the prints from all three emits yet I only get the print for the emit on the window. Which is probably caused by the fact that the signal is not propagating at all.

So where am I going wrong here? And more important how can I achieve the propagating behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: Signals are associated with a GObject class. The `print-this` signal only exists for your `MyWindow` class, not for `GtkButton` or `GtkFrame`, so the `self.button.emit()` and `self.frame.emit()` calls emit nonexistent signals. You wouldn't get anything anyway; even if those signals did exist nothing is connected to them.

Comment: I assumed that `GObject.signal_new` would associate the signal to all GObject classes, but based on your comment I assume this is wrong? So how would I need to define them? (And of course the next step will be how would they then propagate?)

Comment: How do you think signals work? (I don't know Python, but I assume the `GObject.` is calling the GObject class's `signal_new()` instance method on `self`.) Knowing that can help me clear up your misunderstanding.

Comment: Minor nitpick: don't use `time.sleep()` inside your event-driven code. You're blocking the main loop, and it does not what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic GObject signals do not propagate through the GTK widget tree. Only event-related signals do that, and it's done internally [inside GTK](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkmain.c#n2497).

If you want your signal to be recursively emitted you'll have to add a function that calls `g_signal_emit()` on every widget inside the tree.

Comment: Oh that actually makes sense, so for propagation is the above example both the button and frame should relay the signal by connecting to this signal in each of them and then emitting it to its parent using `g_signal_emit`?

Comment: That gets weird fast; remember: signals are synchronous. If you start emitting signals inside signals you get into a possible scalability disaster. I'd rather do what I wrote, and add a signal emitter function that does the hierarchy traversal internally. Also, if you add a signal to a class and you want to emit it on its widget's parent, you also need to add it to the class of the parent.